# How can I use the cssClass attribute in ui:overlayLibray modal?

Tags: modal

I want to remove the padding from the modal-body. That element is 2 layers deep. How can I pass in a style using the cssClass attribute that will be applied to an element nested within and not just on the containing element?

The docs say "cssClass: A comma-separated list of CSS classes for the popover. Applies to visible markup only."